# What would be a simple to use JIT library?

Tags: c, jit

I'm trying to write a language runtime (and a language itself) that is similar to .NET or to the JVM. It's got a form of bytecode that is custom.

What I want is a way to translate said bytecode to actual, runnable machine code. So, because I'm not wanting to write such a translator myself (this is more of a toy project/personal side project) I want to find a good JIT library to use.

Here's what I want the library to do:

- The library should be as easy to use as possible (toy project and I don't really have much experience here)
- The library should support at least x86_64 (development machine), though preferably it should cover other architectures as well
- The library should preferably do some low level optimizations (register tracking and allocation, reducing memory accesses etc); those optimizations shouldn't be very expensive to do though (I will myself do other optimizations to e.g. remove virtual calls and convert them to direct ones, for example). I can accept a library with no optimization if it's easiest to use though.
- The library must have an interface that is usable from C (preferred) or C++ (acceptable).

I will use Boehm GC for garbage collection, if it matters (probably doesn't, but just in case). Maybe a compacting GC would be nice, but I guess I shouldn't combine the questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [llvm](https://llvm.org/). There are some great [tutorials](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) on how to implement your own language with it and basic stuff is not too complicated. You also get the option to do a lot of more advanced stuff later on. As a bonus not only can you use JIT but you can also statically compile and optimize your binaries. LLVM also does have a [C interface](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMC.html) and can target all common CPU architectures and even a lot of more obscure ones.

Comment: I was thinking of llvm myself but I had initially dismissed it as too complex.

Comment: And I'm trying bytecode interpreter on purpose, because I want to be able to load code at runtime.

Comment: llvm supports both JIT and static compilation. So you can do a bytecoder interpreter without issues. The tutorial I linked does in fact implement JIT

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out, though I do feel there's a relatively high barrier of entry. From the linker point of view, I don't want the generated code to have any access to external library code, at least in the initial implementation (though if this gets advanced I'd add support for that as well I guess)

Comment: What your language has access to and what not completely depends on what you implement. (although llvm does make it relatively easy to interface with C/C++ libraries)